# How do I consicely express the templated dereferenced Iterator type as a template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17

Lets say I'm rewriting `std::min_element` for c++17.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element

I'm unhappy with all the overloads. I'd very much like it if (1) and (3) could be expressed in terms of default arguments.

So (3) could replace (1) with

```
template< class ForwardIt, class Compare = typename std::less< ??? >  >
ForwardIt min_element( ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, Compare comp = Compare{});
```

My problem is ??? involves

```
std::remove_reference<decltype((*first){})>.type
```

My intent is to have a specialized `std::less<MyType>` working for any iterator dereferencing to `MyType` and any range using `MyType*`.

With the overload it just becomes

```
 template<typename It>
 It min_element(It first, It last){
 {  auto e = *first;
    return min_element(first, last, std::less<decltype(e)>());
 }
```

calling the

```
 template<typename It, typename Comp>
 It min_element(It first, It last, Comp c){
 {  // it probably needs to be something here, maybe returning an It
 }
```

Is there a concise way to remove the overload with default arguments?

Also I imagine my version to be very buggy.

Comment: "*With the overload it just becomes*" Which you can't do because `first` may not be dereference-able if it happens to equal `last`.

Comment: @NicolBolas *first` exists only in a compile time context.

Comment: What do you mean, "won't be evaluated". You *wrote it* into your code; it *has to be* evaluated. The compiler cannot just ignore the code you wrote, *especially* if it has UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::less<void>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) does work for any type, because its `operator()` is a template and the actual type to be compared is deduced when the operator is called. It was introduced in C++14.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe you dont have the implement it. `std::less<void>` is already what you can use in place of `std::less< ??? >`

Comment: I think OP wants to use `std::less<MyType>` (and not `less<void>`), because it is specialized.

Comment: @MikeMB they can use `std::less<void>` as default argument. When they want to use `std::less<MyType>` then its not the default argument. maybe I dont understand the question...

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Consider the following scenario:I have type `Foo`. I have specialized `std::less<Foo>` (not  overloaded `operator<`). Now have a range `std::vector<Foo> foos;` and want `min_element(foos.begin(), foos.end())` to use std::less<Foo> and not `std::less<void>`, which would use `operator<`

Comment: @MikeMB: If it's so important to you that `less<MyType>` gets called *specifically*, then you should provide it as the comparison operator. Indeed, I would say that specializing `less` at all is a bad idea and can lead to broken-ness. Remember: the only reason `less` and the like exist is so that you can pass operators as callable functors. If it doesn't call the operator, it's not doing its job.

Comment: @NicolBolaa: Sure, and that statement should probably be part of your answer but that's not what the OP asked for and I tried to explain to not_a_number, why his answer doesn't satisfy the OP.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Which reminds me: Aside from being a bad idea. Is it even allowed to specialize std::less for a user defined type? I remember there were some restrictions on which std types one where allowed to specialize.

Comment: @MikeMB Yes, specializing std::less is allowed (encouraged? for types with natural ordering) this is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an iterator type, and you want to get what its `reference` type is, just ask the traits class: `std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference`. And since it's a pre-C++20 ForwardIterator, this is required to be a language reference to `value_type`. So you can just `remove_reference` on it, and you have the type of interest.

C++20 even has a convenient metafunction that does more-or-less the same thing (but it requires C++20-conceptualized iterators): `std::iter_reference_t<Iterator>`. Note that since C++20 forward iterators allow proxy iterators (where `reference` does not have to be `value_type&`), you may need to use `iter_value_t<Iterator>` instead.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: And this would accomplish that goal. `std::iterator_traits<MyType*>::reference` is `MyType&`. If you're using pre-C++20 ForwardIterators, then `reference` is required to be an actual language reference to `value_type`. So just use `remove_reference_t` on it, and you have what you need.